# Lambda expression with functional parameter

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Can you do a lambda expression with a functional parameter, something like:

```
(x = (foo(value)) => ( x != null || x == somethingElse))
```

**Edit:** Linq example (With Selman22's suggestion):

This doesn't work either:

```
result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject((from theme in _themes select new { id = theme.Key, available = (x => { x = _association.getInv(theme.Key); return (x == null || x == guid ); }) }).ToArray<object>());
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve here? Your example isn't really clear...

Comment: Do you want **available** to be a boolean or a function? if it should be a function what is its argument?

Comment: **available** should be a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are creating a lambda statement, and trying to assign it available property:

```
x => { x = _association.getInv(theme.Key); return (x == null || x == guid ); }
```

You might be thinking that this will return a value and assign it to `available` but it is not.Lambda statements are just syntactic sugars for normal methods. So it won't be executed until it's called. In this case you need to create a method that you can pass `theme.Key` as argument, check the result of `getInv` and return the result, then you can just call your function and assign the result to available property

```
select new { id = theme.Key, available = MyFunction(theme.Key) }
```

Comment: That's basically what I just ended up doing.

Comment: It's a better style anyway - it ends up being easier to read, clearer to see the intention.

Answer (score 0):

@Selman22 explained how to solve your problem, but i want to add a bit about difficulties of using lamdas inside LINQ the way you tried to do. The problem is that lambas indeed are just syntactic sugar for delegates, and the compiler has no way to guess exatly which delegate to use when it sees a lambda expression.
Consider the following (completely meaningless) example:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] themes = {1, 2, 3};
        //var a = themes.Select(i => new {f = j => i%2 == 0}); this line gives an error
        var b = themes.Select(i => new {f = new Func<int, bool>(j => i%2 == 0)});
        var c = themes.Select(i => new {f = new MyDelegate(j => i%2 == 0)});
    }

    private delegate bool MyDelegate(int i);
}
```

The line with the `a` variable does not compile because the compiler has no idea if it should create an anonymous class with a field `f` of type `Func<int, bool>` or of type `MyDelegate` or some other delegate. The other two lines are perfectly valid though.

The idea is: be careful when you use lambdas with anonymous types.